# Blender:PoseMode: What is the reason I can't move my thighs (but i CAN move calves and everything else)

Tags: bones, pose-mode

What I did:
I created humanoid character with vertices, then I added skin modifier and created armature from it.

Then i went to armature's posemode and couldnt move my thigs.

When I was extruding, this was the initial order:

- first dot (vertex) was bottom of my pelvis
- then i went up and made upper body
- then (i dont remember in which order) legs, head and hands.

Does order matter?

Comment: hello, what is a thig? the fact that you can't move a part of your mesh with a bone has nothing to do with the order of the extrudes when you modeled the mesh. Once you have finished the modeling, create the armature with the bones followings the limbs, then parent the mesh to the armature, for example with the Automatic Weight option, then test each bone in Pose mode.

Comment: thigh is the upper part of leg above calve below pelvis. Right, i will try your method, thanks

Comment: oh ok, thigh, not thig

Comment: oh yeah my bad sorry

Comment: if you want more help, perhaps show some pictures of your object + armature, or share the file, etc...

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem is without more information/images/what you've tried already. Perhaps uploading your .blend file might help also. I have a feeling you made a mistake somewhere or you need to go in and check weights, or there could be a parenting or constraint error that prevents the movement of the joint. Does the thigh bone move and not take the mesh along with it? Does it not move at all? Does your mesh distrort like crazy or not? We need some more info mate. A couple of images are great for that. Try taking a picture of your rig's hierarchy in your overlay panel.